# Parse setApplicationID - Xcode 6.3/iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode

```
Parse.setApplicationId("****", clientKey: "****") {
```

getting an error saying "expected declaration"...  didn't have this issue on an earlier version of Xcode

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.setApplicationId("Your_application_id",
                clientKey: "Your_Client_Key")
    return true
}
```

And import in your bridging header:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```